# How does numpy addition work?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following unexpected behaviour

```
import numpy as np
class Test:
    def __radd__(self, other):
        print(f'value: {other}')

[1,2,3] + Test()
# prints: value: [1,2,3]
np.array([1,2,3]) + Test()
# prints
# value: 1
# value: 2
# value: 3
```

I would expect the second addition to behave in the same way as the first one, but it doesn't. The only logical explanation I can see is that the numpy `+` operator somehow iterates over the arguments first, and tries to add each one of them to `Test()`, and the second addition `(int + Test)` falls back to the `Test.__radd__`

So

- is there any other explanation that I'm missing?
- if not, how does `a + b` work in numpy
- is it equivalent to `np.add(a, b)`?

Comment: I believe that your explanation is correct.

Comment: The only way to have the right side's `__radd__()` be used in preference to the left side's `__add__()` (in cases where that is actually implemented) is to have the right side be a subclass of the left side.  However, I'm not sure whether numpy arrays can be subclassed - a quick test produced some weird results I can't explain.

Comment: @jasonharper: They can be subclassed, but it's too much work and defeats the purpose of __radd__. Thanks though. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.subclassing.html if you're interested

Comment: There are 2 issues: 1) how `+` is translated into calls to `__add__` or `__radd__` (and for which class), 2) what `ndarray` does when it 'has control'.  Here it appears that `a+Test()` is roughly equivalent to `np.array([Test().__radd__(x) for x in a])` when `a` is a 1d `ndarray`.

Comment: @hpaulj: I think it translates to `[x + Test() for x in a]`. Then, because `x` is an integer, it's out of numpy's control, and python falls back to `Test.__radd__`

Comment: Re your last question `np.add` I'm pretty sure is not 100% equivalent because it takes all its arguments and converts them to array first.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of NumPy ['broadcasting'](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Your explanation is pretty much correct as you can see [in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) for `np.add`.

> **Notes**
>
> Equivalent to x1 + x2 in terms of array broadcasting.

I find this makes a little more sense if you play around with NumPy and see how `np.array` differs from the built-in list.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  6 2016, 16:37:16)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: [1, 2, 3] + [1, 2, 3]
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

In [3]: np.array([1, 2, 3]) + np.array([1, 2, 3])
Out[3]: array([2, 4, 6])
```

Looking at the sourcecode [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/67b9a768a7e6f373bbba02df302622773559ca4b/numpy/lib/mixins.py#L155) for the `NDArrayOperatorsMixin` which `` implements the special methods for almost all of Python's builtin operators defined in the `operator` module ``. It looks like `__add__, __radd__, __iadd__` are all set to the `.add` umath function. **But** I'm not sure if the actual `ndarray` makes use of the mix-in, I think you'd have to dig through the C code to figure out how that's handled.

Comment: It may be equivalent in terms of broadcasting, but the question is whether it is actually equivalent (eg. they are aliases for the same functionality). Also, broadcasting has no part in my case, my object is neither iterable, nor has any shape attribute

Comment: @blue_note `np.array([1, 2, 3]) + 5` works just as well (see Nathan's answer). `numpy` converts your `Test()` to something like `np.array([Test(), Test(), Test()])` internally

Comment: @blue_note ah, apologies - I misunderstood. I'll try to find the right part of the source code to answer your question, if I don't spot it I'll delete this answer, sorry!

Comment: @AaronCritchley: don't delete it. I upvoted it, turns out it seems to be at the right direction

Comment: @blue_note, tried to expand a little, hopefully that's somewhat helpful for you, I think the majority of the core functionality is written in C / Cython though so a little harder than usual to dig through than pure python :(

Comment: I like the detail about the numpy broadcasting concept. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I expand your class a bit we may get more of an idea of when `__add__` is used, and when `__radd__`:

```
class Test:
    def __radd__(self, other):
        print(f'r value: {other}, {type(other)}')
        return f'{other}'
    def __add__(self, other):
        print(f'a value: {other}, {type(other)}')
        return other+3
```

With a list

```
In [285]: [1,2,3]+Test()
r value: [1, 2, 3], <class 'list'>    # use Test.__radd__
Out[285]: '[1, 2, 3]'
In [286]: Test()+[1,2,3]             # tries to use Test.__add__
a value: [1, 2, 3], <class 'list'>
....
<ipython-input-280-cd3f564be47a> in __add__(self, other)
      5     def __add__(self, other):
      6         print(f'a value: {other}, {type(other)}')
----> 7         return other+3
      8 
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

With an array:

```
In [287]: np.arange(3)+Test()     # use Test.__radd__ with each array element
r value: 0, <class 'int'>
r value: 1, <class 'int'>
r value: 2, <class 'int'>
Out[287]: array(['0', '1', '2'], dtype=object)
In [288]: Test()+np.arange(3)
a value: [0 1 2], <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Out[288]: array([3, 4, 5])    # use Test.__add__ on whole array
```

With itself, a double use of `Test.__add__`:

```
In [289]: Test()+Test()
a value: <__main__.Test object at 0x7fc33a5a7a20>, <class '__main__.Test'>
a value: 3, <class 'int'>
Out[289]: 6
```

As I commented it can be tricky sorting out the `__add__` v `__radd__` delegation, and separating that from `ndarray` action.

---

`add` with `Test()` second gives the same output as [287]:

```
In [295]: np.add(np.arange(3),Test())
r value: 0, <class 'int'>
r value: 1, <class 'int'>
r value: 2, <class 'int'>
Out[295]: array(['0', '1', '2'], dtype=object)
```

`np.add` with `Test()` first is different from [288] above:

```
In [296]: np.add(Test(),np.arange(3))
a value: 0, <class 'int'>
a value: 1, <class 'int'>
a value: 2, <class 'int'>
Out[296]: array([3, 4, 5], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct. Numpy adds each element. You can see this behavior with primitives as well:

```
np.array([1,2,3]) + 1  # [2,3,4]
```